# Blackboard Learn 9.1 - supported LIS 2.0 operations

Tags: blackboard

Does anyone know of a list of the supported operations that Blackboard Learn 9.1 April 2014 supports?  I know it conforms to LIS 2.0 Final specifications, but there are many operations within those specs that don't seem to be supported.  For the life of me, I can't find any documentation from them that explains what's supported and what's not.  I'm mainly interested in the Outcomes Management Service and Person Management service.  And if there was any sample code, especially for the Outcomes one, that would be excellent.  The Outcomes service seems to be the one that's omitted the most.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Outcomes Management Service service is supported by the LIS 2.0 Final version (LIS 2.0 Draft did not support it yet) and the Person Management Service is supported by the LIS 2.0 Draft version, according to the [LIS-IMS Learning Information Services](https://help.blackboard.com/en-us/Learn/9.1_2014_04/Administrator/070_Server_Management_and_Integrations/System_Integration/Student_Information_System_(SIS)/030_SIS_Integration_Types/030_LIS) web page for Blackboard release April 2014.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree @jbr, I edited my answer to make it more useful and detailed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did see that the service was supported, but within the service there are many specific operations, many of which don't seem to be supported yet by Blackboard, but for the life of me I can't find any documentation stating what's supported or not.  But if I use SoapUI on some, I get back an error stating that it's unsupported.  Rather than hitting every single operation to find out, I was hoping it was documented somewhere.

Comment: @mppowe can you give an example of what exactly are you trying to do when getting that error?

Comment: For example, when trying to invoke the "discoverResultIds" operation (in the Outcomes Management Service) via SOAPUI, I would get back an error about the operation being unsupported.  Other operations, such as the "readPerson" operation (in the Person Management Service) did not return that error, so I presume it's supported by Blackboard at this time.